# JAXB, save type of fields

Tags: java, types, jaxb, marshalling

How can I save types of class fields after marshalling without using of annotation. How can I edit it without annotations? What's the best way so it looks like in the example below?

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:o xmlns:ns2="info.source4code.jaxb.model">
    <test>aaaa</test>
    <intTest>100</intTest>
    <abc>2</abc>
</ns2:o>
```

Wanted output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:o xmlns:ns2="info.source4code.jaxb.model">
    <test type="String">aaaa</test>
    <intTest type="Integer">100</intTest>
    <abc type="Integer">2</abc>
</ns2:o>
```

Comment: Is it a good idea to blow up XML data by adding the type information repeatedly for each element? The JAXB marshaller doesn't do this unless you use annotations - which you have excluded. An XML schema (which you can obtain by running schemagen) would have type information, although not as Java types. (You omitted package names - why?)

Comment: Could you not manually add an attribute to your schema that defines the datatype? You already have to declare the element and what datatype it is, it doesn't seem unfeasible to add an attribute to it.